# Automating QGIS Choropleth Maps Using PyQgis

Tags: pyqgis, choropleth

I have maps (shapefiles - vector layers) of several states' school districts, appended to a federal dataset containing the same variables for each state's districts (in the attribute table). I want to create a set of choropleth maps, one for each state, color-coding districts by levels of a given variable in the attribute table.

Does anyone know of a tutorial (or can someone share some code) that would let me automate the creation of these maps using QGIS's built-in Python interface, including specification of the colors (preferably in RGB) to represent each level of the variable?

Comment: Are you starting from raster or vector layers? Which is the format of the expected result? Please add more informations to your question (the best would be also a graphical sample of your input data).